# Excel Filter(Filter()) Function. Filtering an array by columns and by rows based on dropdown selection

Tags: excel, filter, syntax, logic

I have a table consisting of multiple rows and 7 columns. Many of the cells are empty.

I would like to create a summary table from that table, in which I filter for 2 columns using the Filter() function. Then the third column is filtered from a dropdown menu. I manage to get that using:

```
FILTER(Table1;((Table1[#Headers]="Checklist Item 1")+(Table1[#Headers]="Responsible")+(Table1[#Headers]=Q6)))
```

where Q6 is my column dropdown.

Now the summary table is a dynamic array, all nice and good, but it contains all the blanks.

Now I would like to remove all the blanks. I manage to do that, if I nest the Filter function in another Filter function, that filters for rows, like this:

```
=FILTER(
(FILTER(Table1;((Table1[#Headers]="Checklist Item 1")+(Table1[#Headers]="Responsible")+(Table1[#Headers]=Q6))));
Table1[S]<>"")
```

But I hard-coded the last filter part here where I filter for Table1[S]<>"". Instead of hard coding that one, I would like pick the column to filter from from a drop down in cell Q6. Something like Table1["column chosen in Q6"]<>"" but I cant get the syntax right.

Any ideas? I've been hard stuck for quite a while. Thank you.

Example image in below link

(note, my Excel uses semicolon instead of comma for argument separation)

[See Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOvLj.png)

Comment: Have you tried `INDIRECT("Table1["&Q6&"]")<>"")`. You could also use INDEX and MATCH to avoid volatility: `INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH(Q6,Table1[#Headers],0))`

Comment: Wow, thank you Rory. I have no idea (yet) what INDIRECT does, but I will find out. It works! Thank you